git cherry-pick from another repo with a different directory structure
I am attempting to cherry-pick a commit from one repo to another, but the 2 repos unfortunately differ by one directory level (but are otherwise very similar), i.e. there is an extra directory at the top of the directory structure in the repo which will be receiving the commit. Is there a way to account for this different directory structure when performing the cherry pick, or is this going to be a manual file change operation?

You should be able to save the diff and use patch to apply it, maybe with some minor editing of the patch itself.

Use git diff --relative=extra-top-level-dir.

I've had to do such cherry picks before, and Git actually automatically matched my patch to the right file in the other repo. I'm not sure what heuristics it was using, but somehow the magic worked for me. So my first attempt to just be to try the "dumb" thing and cherry pick directly. Not guarantees of success, of course, but worth a try imho.

@joanis oh I definitely tried this and it did not work. The two I'm working with must not have the same "link" that yours do.

Ah, OK, then obviously you'll need something like suggested in the earlier comments. Thanks for confirming.
